# Java 8 stream API orElse usage

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What I'm trying to do is to filter the list, then map it and use `orElse` if `null` and then collect it back to the list.  Now I can achieve it this way:

```
return users.stream()
    .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
    .map(
        user -> {
            if(user.getData() != null) {
                return user.getData();
            }
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the question is: how can I make this structure better and why cannot I use `orElse` in this case?

Comment: Maybe your `User::getData` should return a `Optional<Map<K, V>>` then you can apply `...map(user -> user.getData().orElseGet(this::emptyMap))....`.

Comment: What's the `emptyMap` in the question what are `getData` and `getId`, a basic object schema would be helpful unless you just want people to keep speculating.

Comment: `getData` should best return an empty collection instead of `null`. Returning `null` for no elements is bad practice.

Comment: I highly doubt that you might just be looking for `users.stream()
                .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()) && user.getData() != null)
                .map(User::getData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`... but then the question isn't clear enough to say what `emptyMap` is or what is the eventual return type of your statement is!! I mean who knows if there is an `Optional` even involved in the above operation at all.

Comment: @nullpointer it's just Collections.emptyMap()

Comment: @MykytaBezverkhyi Ya [as I assumed it to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53610360/1746118), what's the use of filling in a `List<Map<K,V>>` with empty maps and that too when they are actually returned as `null`!

Comment: @nullpointer 1) since it's a terrible practice to return null; 2) since I'm gonna use this list later and I don't wanna additional null checks

Comment: @MykytaBezverkhyi No, don't add nulls to the List, agreed ... and that's where the solution I'd proposed would filter the `null`s out.

Comment: @nullpointer I got your point, I don't need it to be out, I need the same list size to use it after

Comment: What I want to know is what does stream do here to justify not simply using for-each? (unless you are getting paid per line of code)

Comment: @Tezra we prefer to use Java 8 in all of the purposes of our project

Comment: @MykytaBezverkhyi Performance penalty of using streams aside, doesn't this question prove that this method of doing it is not maintainable enough to avoid using a simple for-each loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be more readable with ternary conditional operator:

```
return users.stream()
    .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
    .map(
        user -> (user.getData() != null) 
        ? user.getData() 
        : emptyMap()
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

In order to use `orElse` you'll have to create an `Optional` that wraps `user.getData()`. I'm not sure that's a good idea.

If you insist on using `orElse` (or even better, `orElseGet`, to avoid evaluating `emptyMap()` when it's not required), it can look like this:

```
return users.stream()
    .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
    .map(
        user -> Optional.ofNullable(
            user.getData()
        ).orElseGet(
            () -> emptyMap()
        )
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

Comment: since Collections.emptyMap() is a constant we can simply use orElse(emptyMap()), but thanks

Comment: @MykytaBezverkhyi I see. That wasn't clear from your original question. You're welcome!

Comment: Typo `user.getDate()`, should be `user.getData()` ... and @Eran I really doubt one should be using `Optional` for this use case anyway. I mean what sense would it make to add emptyMap to a List of Maps for a condition when they are actually null ?

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks about the typo. I agree about not using `Optional` (that's why I started with a ternary conditional operator). As to whether or not it makes sense to add `emptyMap`s to that `List`, it depends on the real world use-case, which we don't know.

Comment: @Eran it's definitely makes sense in my case, I actually prefer Optionals just in case it looks better

Comment: Java 9+: `.map(user -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(user.getData(), emptyMap()))`. The ternary operator has the disadvantage that it may invoke `getData()` twice.

Comment: ...or even [Objects.requireNonNullElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet(T,java.util.function.Supplier))

Comment: @Hulk no need to use `Objects::requireNonNullElseGet`, `Objects::requireNonNullElse` (see my answer) suffices. `Collections::emptyMap` is relatively lightweight since it only casts and returns a constant: `public static final <K,V> Map<K,V> emptyMap() { return (Map<K,V>) EMPTY_MAP; }`

Answer (score 4):

As I pointed out in the comments as well and I highly doubt that you might just be looking for the following

```
users
    .stream()
    .filter(
        user -> id.equals(user.getId()) 
        && (user.getData() != null)
    )
    .map(User::getData)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

But then the question isn't clear enough to say what is the eventual return type of your statement is or what is the `emptyMap` used in your code! Hence I highly doubt, if you even need an `Optional` API in first place for this operation.

Note: The above-stated solution does assume that `emptyMap` is `Collections.emptyMap` which I am not sure why would one want to collect in a data structure which is denoted as `List<Map<K,V>>`.

Comment: `.filter(user -> user != null && ...)`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko why? is a `user` would be `null` there would have been an NPE thrown for code in the question itself.. isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's not something that I need, and sorry if my question is not clear

Comment: @MykytaBezverkhyi well sure, just wanted to clarify certain things as a practice... was eventually curious to know if a List with empty Map could actually serve a good purpose in any use case. Updates to the question made it clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make this structure better

Method 1:

```
return users.stream()
    .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
    .map(
        user -> (user.getData() != null)
        ? user.getData() 
        : emptyMap()
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

Method 2:

Make your `getData` return an `Optional`: `user -> user.getData().orElse(emptyMap())`

Method 3:

As @Eran said: `Optional.ofNullable` then use `orElse(emptyMap())` like above: `user -> Optional.ofNullable(user.getData()).orElse(emptyMap())`

> Why I cannot use orElse in this case?

Not sure what `orElse` you mean

1. If `user.getData()` returns `null`, it should be wrapped to an `Optional` to call `orElse`.
2. The stream's `findAny().orElse` operates on the stream's result itself. But what you need here is to check if `user.getData()` exists. So you can not use stream's result's `orElse` directly.

Answer (score 1):

### Use [`Objects::requireNonNullElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T))!

I would advise of of two things to make the code more readable. I would not, however, artificially introduce an `Optional`.

---

### First option: `Objects::requireNonNullElse` in a separate method

```
List<Map<?, ?> bar() {
    //...

    return users.stream()
                .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
                .map(User::getData)
                .map(Foo::nullSafeMap)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Map<?, ?> nullSafeMap(final Map<?, ?> map) {
    return Objects.requireNonNullElse(map, Collections.emptyMap());
}
```

Here, you would use `Objects::requireNonNullElse`, which returns the object passed in the first parameter if it is not `null`, and the object passed as the second parameter if the first parameter is `null`. Having a separate method allows for a method reference to be passed to `Stream::map`, but requires you to first map the `User` instances to their data `Map`.

---

### Second option: Inline `Objects::requireNonNullElse`

```
List<Map<?, ?> bar() {
    //...

    return users.stream()
                .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
                .map(User::getData)
                .map(map -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(map, Collections.emptyMap()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you do not want a separate method to do just this single task, you can inline the method and optionally even remove the first mapping in favor of `.map(user -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(user.getData(), Collections.emptyMap()))`, but I would advise against this. Don't be afraid to have multiple calls to `Stream::map` if it makes the code more readable.

---

### Conclusion

I would **prefer the first option** as it makes the code very readable: You know that you map the `User` instances to the data, then you make that data null safe.

The second option is alright, but suffers from a very long line that might be confusing on the first glance. It is much better than having a multi-line lambda though. **I would avoid multi-line lambdas at all costs and always extract their contents into a separate method.**

One thing you might be able to improve upon is the method name `nullSafeMap`, as to avoid confusion between `Stream::map` and `java.util.Map`.

Note that you don't need to use [`Objects::requireNonNullElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet(T,java.util.function.Supplier)) since `Collections::emptyMap` is a lightweight method that only casts and returns a constant:

```
public static final <K,V> Map<K,V> emptyMap() {
    return (Map<K,V>) EMPTY_MAP;
}
```

`Objects::requireNonNullElseGet` is made for default objects whose retrieval or creation is heavyweight.

Comment: [vertically coupling lines discourages renaming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/331680/131624)

Comment: @candied_orange Interesting point, however with automatic renaming refactorings and automatic code formatting there's little to be worried about. I for one have never thought that renaming the variable will destroy my pretty vertical alignment, because I don't manually align multi-line method call chains anyways. It's all done for me by the formatter, and I slam CTRL+ALT+L every two seconds anyways (And format before pushing just in case). I'd be more inclined to agree if I we were still using a dumb text editor, but not on an IDE :-)

Comment: It still causes annoying false positives in source control diff tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have [Apache Collections 4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#emptyIfNull-java.util.Map-) as dependency:

```
return users
    .stream()
    .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getId()))
    .map(User::getData)
    .map(MapUtils::emptyIfNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

If you don't use Apache Collections just define a helper method:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> emptyIfNull(Map<K,V> map) {
    return map == null ? Collections.<K,V>emptyMap() : map;
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to accommodate the `null is emptyMap` requirement.

Comment: I liked this better when it didn't have 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: There are both variants - and helper method is trivial enough to put us in you own class